# Range Overlap Bar Chart

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, charts, bar-chart

I am creating a Range Overlap Bar Chart that should display multi-value in a single bar and should change the color.  In order to make what I want say clear I made a draw:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by multi-value in a single bar? A bar corresponds to one value...

Comment: Have look at this: https://www.google.cz/search?q=Range+Overlap+Bar+Chart&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&imgil=M4L-hkTcvBk0wM%253A%253Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fencrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com%252Fimages%253Fq%253Dtbn%253AANd9GcRT_ZoLtHxL6jnBkmpoe3qQ8N_wiEJ4lOFw0-gYyS8d8ghfZfKf%253B429%253B265%253BZ-zuoy1nmlE_eM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.sqljason.com%25252F2012%25252F03%25252Foverlapping-charts-in-ssrs-using-range.html&source=iu&usg=__bminI-U5GTrYsJXNjjGyba4FJv4%3D&sa=X&ei=d7CUU4XcKIasO8-DgcgO&ved=0CDcQ9QEwAw&dur=2843

Comment: What's your question? Is this WPF or Winforms? (you have both tagged)

Comment: IMO this is off topic because it's just a matter of finding some charting library that will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Chart Controls in Visual Studio toolbox. You will have to create multiple series as you want to show an overlap chart. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd489221(v=vs.100).aspx) will help you.

Here is some code...

```
DataSet dataSet;
ConnectionClass.GetInstance().connection_string = Properties.Settings.Default.MindMuscleConnectionString;
ConnectionClass.GetInstance().Sql = "Select Count(MemberInfo.memberName) as 'Members', CompetitionName as 'Competition' FROM MemberInfo, MemberBodyInfo, Competition WHERE MemberInfo.memberID = MemberBodyInfo.memberID AND MemberBodyInfo.weight >= Competition.CompetitionCategory and MemberBodyInfo.weight <= Competition.CompetitionCategory + 5 group by CompetitionName;";
dataSet = ConnectionClass.GetInstance().GetConnection;
chart1.Series["Series1"].Name = "Members";
chart1.Series["Members"].YValueMembers = "Members";
chart1.Series["Members"].XValueMember = "Competition";
chart1.Series.Add("Members2");
chart1.Series["Members2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
chart1.Series["Members2"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
chart1.Series["Members2"].YValueMembers = "Members";
chart1.Series["Members2"].XValueMember = "Competition";
this.chart1.Titles.Add("Competition Participants");   // Set the chart title
chart1.Series["Members"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
chart1.Series["Members"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;  // To show chart value 
chart1.DataSource = dataSet;
chart1.DataBind();
```

It will look like:

[image]

I have not actually created a new series from some different data... Both series are same here but I have just showed you an example. You will have to populate your series using your data.

Now if you change

```
chart1.Series["Members2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
chart1.Series["Members"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
```

to

```
chart1.Series["Members2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar;
chart1.Series["Members"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar;
```

The chart will look like exactly your drawing:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<UserControl x:Class="Budget.Summary.UserCtrlChartCategories"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         
         xmlns:dxc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/charts" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Budget.Summary"
         mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="userCtrl"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" 
         Loaded="UserControl_Loaded" 
         Unloaded="UserControl_Unloaded" >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyExpenseBarDataPointStyle" TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:BarDataPoint}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5, 0.5"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1.0"/>
                    <TranslateTransform  Y="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=chartingToolkit:BarDataPoint},Converter={StaticResource NegativeValueConverter}}" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:BarDataPoint}">
                    <Border x:Name="Root"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Border.ToolTip>
                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}" />
                        </Border.ToolTip>
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Rectangle>
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#77FFFFFF"  Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#CCFFFFFF"  BorderThickness="1">
                                <Border BorderBrush="#77FFFFFF"  BorderThickness="1" />
                            </Border>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionHighlight" Fill="Red" Opacity="0" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="MouseOverHighlight" Fill="White" Opacity="0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MyBudgetBarDataPointStyle"
     TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:BarDataPoint}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:BarDataPoint}">
                    <Border x:Name="Root"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Border.ToolTip>
                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}" />
                        </Border.ToolTip>
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Rectangle>
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#77FFFFFF"  Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#CCFFFFFF"  BorderThickness="1">
                                <Border BorderBrush="#77FFFFFF"  BorderThickness="1" />
                            </Border>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionHighlight" Fill="Red" Opacity="0" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="MouseOverHighlight" Fill="White" Opacity="0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>


<Grid>
    <Grid >
        <!--https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/bar-chart-in-wpf/-->
        <chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="LineChart"  
            Title="{Binding Title,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Margin="10,10,10,0" 
               Background="LightBlue" >
            <chartingToolkit:Chart.Resources>
            </chartingToolkit:Chart.Resources>

            <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis  Orientation="X" />
            </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Style MyExpenseBarDataPointStyle = (Style)this.FindResource("MyExpenseBarDataPointStyle");
Style MyBudgetBarDataPointStyle = (Style)this.FindResource("MyBudgetBarDataPointStyle");
BarSeries barSeriesExpense = new BarSeries();
barSeriesExpense.Name = Name.Replace(" ", "");
BarSeries barSeriesBudget = new BarSeries();
barSeriesBudget.Title = "Budget";
barSeriesBudget.Name = Name.Replace(" ", "");
barSeriesExpense.Title = "Dépense";
barSeriesExpense.DataPointStyle = MyExpenseBarDataPointStyle;
barSeriesBudget.DataPointStyle = MyBudgetBarDataPointStyle;


barSeriesExpense.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Key"); //date  l'axe des X
barSeriesExpense.DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value"); //money l'axe des Y
barSeriesBudget.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Key"); //date  l'axe des X
barSeriesBudget.DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value"); //money l'axe des Y
barSeriesExpense.ItemsSource = dataSource;
barSeriesBudget.ItemsSource = dataSourceMax;
LineChart.Series.Add(barSeriesBudget);
LineChart.Series.Add(barSeriesExpense);
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Here is an example of adding 2 bar series to a chart in code. In the XAML we are modifhing the bardatapoint style with a render transform to shift vertically the last serie to overlap with tbe first one.